# How to Make Axios AbortController Wait for Server Response?

Tags: javascript, axios

I'm using axios for my http requests, and `AbortController` to abort them.

And I figured that running `conroller.abort()` will throw an error immediatly and doesn't wait for the server response, and the server sometime will keep processing until it hits the request cancelled at last, i.e. after running the process completely.

So I want to wait for the server after the `abort` is called, if the server returned my custom status code `499` then it's canceled safely, otherwise, run the normal process for success or error codes.

Does `cancelToken.source()` work in this case, and is it recommended?

Comment: The point of `AbortController` is to cancel the request in progress. Whenever you  get a response, there will be nothing to abort. Could you add the relevant part of your code to the question?